# Sql Query is not valid

Tags: php, html, mysql

i am working on jquery data table with help of jquery plug in. I am fetching data from data base. But i don't know why my sql query is not valid, but query is totally correct.

```
<?php
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root","","data_table");
    $query = "select * from data_table";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    ?>
```

Comment: What error do you get back? What have you debugged so far, what is the dump of `$result`?

Comment: Do you have both a database *and* a table called `data_table`?

Comment: @Qirel bool(false)
Invalid query:

Comment: So your query is not "totally correct". My guess is that you don't have a table called `data_table`, and that `data_table` is the database itself.

Comment: @Qirel  Done sir, my data base name is wrong thank you for your time and efforts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please put your database name

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root","","YourDatabaseName");
```

please put your database table name

```
$query = "select * from DatabaseTableName";
```